# How to use 22 pixel size icons for toolbars in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: icons, 14.04, gedit, icon-themes

Is there a way to tell the theme engine to use 22 pixel size icons for toolbars?

I like to use the FS Icon set (http://franksouza183.deviantart.com/art/FS-Icons-Ubuntu-288407674) with Ubuntu.  However, in Ubuntu 14.04, Gedit (and perhaps some other programs as well) now use 24 pixel size icons.  The gedit toolbar requires 24 pixel size icons, but 
the FS Icon set has 22 pixel icons, and the next larger size is 32 pixel icons.

As a result, the available icons are scaled to fit the gedit toolbar, and "fallback" icons are used for anything that is missing.  As you can see in the screen-shot below, the gedit icons look fuzzy under Ubuntu 14.04.  Also, the monochromatic icons for the "Open", "Search", and "Search & Replace" tools are missing, so uncoordinated colored icons are used instead.

[image: Gedit in Ubuntu 14.04 with Fuzzy and Missing Mono-Dark FS Icons]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use the 22 pixel FS icons as 24 pixel icons.  This is done by creating links to the 22 pixel icons and updating the FS Icon theme configuration files.

**1)** Execute the following command if you need to be root to make changes to your FS Icons installation...

```
$ sudo -i
```

**2)** Change to the location where you've installed the FS Icons (ex. /usr/share/icons/)...

```
$ cd <location where fs icons are installed>
```

**3)** For 24 px size icons, link to the existing 22 px size icons...

```
$ for file in `ls ./ | grep fs-icons-ubuntu`; do ln -s 22x22 ./$file/24x24; done
```

**4)** In index.theme, add the 24 px size icons to the available Desktop, Toolbar, MainToolbar, Small, Panel, and Dialog sizes...

```
$ sed -i "s|22,|22,24,|g" ./fs-icons-ubuntu*/index.theme
```

**5)** In index.theme, add the 24 px size icon directories...

```
$ sed -i "s|22x22/status,|22x22/status,24x24/actions,24x24/animations,24x24/apps,24x24/categories,24x24/devices,24x24/emblems,24x24/mimetypes,24x24/places,24x24/status,|g" ./fs-icons-ubuntu*/index.theme
```

**6)** In index.theme, add 24 px size icon metadata for actions, animations, apps, categories, devices, emblems, mimetypes, places, status...

```
$ sed -i "s|\[32x32/actions\]|\n[24x24/actions]\nSize=24\nContext=Actions\nType=Threshold\n\n[24x24/animations]\nSize=24\nContext=Animations\nType=Threshold\n\n[24x24/apps]\nSize=24\nContext=Applications\nType=Threshold\n\n[24x24/categories]\nSize=24\nContext=Categories\nType=Threshold\n\n[24x24/devices]\nSize=24\nContext=Devices\nType=Threshold\n\n[24x24/emblems]\nSize=24\nContext=Emblems\nType=Threshold\n\n[24x24/mimetypes]\nSize=24\nContext=MimeTypes\nType=Threshold\n\n[24x24/places]\nSize=24\nContext=Places\nType=Threshold\n\n[24x24/status]\nSize=24\nContext=Status\nType=Threshold\n\n\n\n[32x32/actions]|g" ./fs-icons-ubuntu*/index.theme
```

**7)** Update icon caches. (You may ignore "generated cache was invalid" warnings).

```
$ for file in `ls ./ | grep fs-icons-ubuntu`; do echo "Updating cache for $file..."; gtk-update-icon-cache -f ./$file; done
```

**8)** Execute the following only if you did "sudo -i" in step 1 above.

```
$ exit
```

Here is what the the gedit window looks like with the corrected icons.  Notice that the icons are sharp and that only monochromatic icons are used in the toolbar.

[image: Gedit in Ubuntu 14.04 with Sharp Mono-Dark FS Icons]

Finally, here is the Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop using the FS Icons (specifically the "fs-icons-ubuntu-mono-dark" icons).

[image: Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop using the FS Mono Dark Icons]