# How to fix huge FS Icons in Ubuntu 15.04 menubars?

Tags: icons, 15.04

The [FS Icons](http://franksouza183.deviantart.com/art/FS-Icons-Ubuntu-288407674) in Ubuntu 15.04 appear huge in the menubars of some applications like Nautilus, Gedit, Calculator, etc.  How can the FS icon sizes be corrected to work in Ubuntu 15.04?

Here is what the icons look like in Nautilus.  This makes the operating system difficult to use when FS Icons are installed and used.

[image: Huge FS Icons in Nautilus Ubuntu 15.04]

Here is an example of the icons in Gedit.

[image: Large FS Icons in Gedit Ubuntu 15.04]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, scalable icons are used in the menubars for Ubuntu 15.04.  The FS Icon set specifies a minimum value for the scalable icons as 257 pixels.  The solution is to set the minimum value appropriately, so the icons can be scaled down to the required size.

```
sudo sed -i "s|MinSize=|MinSize=8\n#MinSize=|g" /usr/share/icons/fs-icons-ubuntu*/index.theme
```

In the above command, change `/usr/share/icons` to the location where you have installed your FS Icon set.

Additionally, in order to fix the icon sizes in Gedit, follow the steps outlined in the following question, since the fix still applies to Ubuntu 15.04.

[How to use 22 pixel size icons for toolbars in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454852/how-to-use-22-pixel-size-icons-for-toolbars-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Note that *fs-icons-ubuntu-mono-dark* were used in these screen shots, but this solution will fix all of the icons included in the FS Icons set.

Here is what Nautilus looks like after applying the fix.

[image: Corrected FS Icons in Nautilus Ubuntu 15.04]

Here is what Gedit looks like after applying the fix.

[image: Corrected FS Icons in Gedit Ubuntu 15.04]

Answer (score 0):

I just edited the *index.theme* file which is placed in the icon theme folder. I inserted the line MinSize=24 under each **[icon size]** with Type=Scalable. For me it worked for MeliaeSVG icon on Ubuntu 15.10 using Unity. See image below.

[image: Editing index.theme to correct icons size]

Answer (score 0):

I just edited the lines with [scalable/...] headers from 'MinSize=257' to 'MinSize=24' in *index.theme file* . And the situation is fixed.
My linux is ubuntu gnome 17.04

[scalable/actions]
Size=331
Context=Actions
Type=Scalable
**MinSize=24**
MaxSize=512

[scalable/animations]
Size=331
Context=Animations
Type=Scalable
**MinSize=24**
MaxSize=512

[scalable/apps]
Size=331
Context=Applications
Type=Scalable
**MinSize=24**
MaxSize=512

[scalable/categories]
Size=331
Context=Categories
Type=Scalable
**MinSize=24**
MaxSize=512

[scalable/devices]
Size=331
Context=Devices
Type=Scalable
**MinSize=24**
MaxSize=512

[scalable/emblems]
Size=331
Context=Emblems
Type=Scalable
**MinSize=24**
MaxSize=512

[scalable/mimetypes]
Size=331
Context=MimeTypes
Type=Scalable
**MinSize=24**
MaxSize=512

[scalable/places]
Size=331
Context=Places
Type=Scalable
**MinSize=24**
MaxSize=512

[scalable/status]
Size=331
Context=Status
Type=Scalable
**MinSize=24**
MaxSize=512