# ubuntu icons size after upgrade 15.04

Tags: nautilus, icons, 15.04

I recently upgraded my ubuntu linux to 15.04. Some of the places icon size is too big after upgrade. I have attached some images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about with the default themes Ambiance or Radiance?

Comment: It not because of theme... I changed the theme.. still it visibling icons are visibling big. its not happening for all applications. happening for nautilus, calc... I think nautilus supported application only happening...

Comment: Are you using a third party repository for nautilus or similar?

Comment: I am not using any third party repository for nautilus.... Using the default one from ubuntu....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fix for FS icons on this link [How to fix huge FS Icons in Ubuntu 15.04 menubars?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616132/how-to-fix-huge-fs-icons-in-ubuntu-15-04-menubars)

I have tried with FS icons and it works for me, fixing the issue you report and also the huge icons in menus and titles. It did not fix other icon sets though :-(